How to parameterize the SQL file dynamically to execute in Airflow BigQuery Operator - GCP
I have a case where I need to pick the SQL file dynamically based on the given condition and need to pass it to BigqueryOperator to execute in DAG.
# airflow variable
SQL1 = 'SQL1.sql'
SQL2 = 'SQL2.sql'
SQL_to_run = ''

def condition_check():
    if weekday = 'Sunday':
        SQL_to_run = 'SQL1.sql'
    elif weekday = 'Monday':
        SQL_to_run = 'SQL2.sql'
    else:
        print('no run')

with DAG(dag_id="DAG_NM",
        start_date=datetime(2024,2,21),
        template_searchpath = ['/usr/local/airflow/dags/resources/'],
        schedule_interval="0 10 * * 7#1,7#2",
        default_args=default_args,
        catchup=False) as dag:

type_of_sql_task = PythonOperator(
                            task_id="type_of_extract",
                            python_callable=condition_check,
                            provide_context=True,
        )

execute_sql_data_task = BigQueryOperator(
                            task_id="Execute_data",
                            sql=SQL_to_run
                            params={'projectid' : project_name,'dataset': dataset},
                            use_legacy_sql=False
                            )

SQL_to_run is not recogonized in Bigquery Operator, I tried to do the xcom push / pull as well, but not able to achieve the requirement.
Can someone please let me know how to get the SQL file name dynamically / assign it to a variable and use it in Bigquery Operator based on condition?

What do you mean by "SQL_to_run is not recognizable"?

SQL_to_run parameter is initialized in the start of the process and that variable is assigned with the SQL file name dynamically in the First Task and that variable is reused in the Bigquery Operator, but the variable is not working as expected

in your sql file use jinja conditions
